# Reading stdin into a bash array

Tags: bash, array, read

I want to accomplish the equivalent of:

```
list=()
while read i; do
  list+=("$i")
done <<<"$input"
```

with

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -a list <<<"$input"
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
input=`/bin/ls /`

IFS=$'\n' read -r -a list <<<"$input"

for i in "${list[@]}"; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

This should print a listing of `/`, but I'm only getting the first item.

Comment: If you are really trying to parse the output of `ls`, don't. Use `list=(/*)`.

Answer (score 17):

You must use [mapfile](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile) (or its synonym [readarray](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-readarray), which was introduced in `bash 4.0`):

```
mapfile -t list <<<"$input"
```

One [read](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) invocation only work with one line, not the entire standard input.

`read -a list` populate the content of first line of standard in to the array `list`. In your case, you got `bin` as the only element in array `list.

Comment: @cuonglm The `IFS` is useless, because `mapfile` doesn't do any word-splitting on its input.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: My bad, removed it.

Answer (score 6):

for `bash` versions that do not support `mapfile`

```
IFS=$'\n' read -ra list -d '' <<< "$input"
```

should do the trick

Comment: One minor drawback; this command will always have a non-zero exit status.

Comment: Also note that it removes empty elements.

Answer (score 5):

### Solution for Bash version 3 (and 4)

I happened to be logged in to a CentOS 5 box running Bash 3 and I had been working on a solution. I’ve already upvoted cuonglm’s answer but I thought I may as well post the solution I came up with that should work with Bash 3 (and 4). I’ve tested it with a file which had a space in its name and another which begins with `-`.

Instead of

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -a list <<<"$input"
```

simply use command substitution to create and populate the array:

```
IFS=$'\n' # split on newline only
set -f    # disable globbing
list=($(printf "%s" "$input"))
```

Note: This won’t work with filenames which have newlines in their name.